# Select element and subsequent text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having following markup:

```
<div class="controls">
  <input type="radio" id="sex" name="sex" value="m"> Boy
  <input type="radio" id="sex" name="sex" value="f"> Girl
  <input type="radio" id="sex" name="sex" value="t"> Twins
</div>
```

How can I select each radio button and it's subsequent text. My goal is to wrap both in a label, so the output would be:

```
<div class="controls">
  <label><input type="radio" id="sex" name="sex" value="m"> Boy</label>
  <label><input type="radio" id="sex" name="sex" value="f"> Girl</label>
  <label><input type="radio" id="sex" name="sex" value="t"> Twins</label>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the markup is created by a CMS. (It also adds `id="sex"` multiple times, blergh).

Comment: Sounds like you need a better CMS...

Comment: Yeah, you should never have duplicate IDs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortest I can think of:

```js
$('.controls :radio').each(function() {
    $(this).add(this.nextSibling).wrapAll('<label>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="controls">
  <input type="radio" id="sex" name="sex" value="m"> Boy
  <input type="radio" id="sex" name="sex" value="f"> Girl
  <input type="radio" id="sex" name="sex" value="t"> Twins
</div>
```

Comment: That's it! Didn't know about the .add() function.